# Identifying Redirect/Forward Action in Struts2 Incerceptor

Tags: redirect, struts2, action, interceptor

I was looking for a way to identify Struts 2 actions which are of type 'Redirect/Forward' in Interceptor, so that I can add some common code for that particular type of Action.

Is there any way in Struts2 to find what type of Action it is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing called as RedirectAction or ForwardAction, what you need it Redirect Result Type.

In your interceptor you have an instance of `ActionInvocation` passes to your `intercept` method, you can get the result from `ActionInvocation` object and then check as per your use case. Different Results are listed [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Result.html)

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) {
   //After invoking the action you can get the result of from ActionInvocation.
   Result result = actionInvocation.getResult();
   //As per your use case you can check against different types.
}
```